# Transfer Dataframe to Excel with Slicer functionality

Tags: python, excel

There is a Dataframe with data pic.1 [image]
Is it possible using the libraries openpyxl, win32com, etc. to transfer Dataframe to Excel to get the view pic.2, with Excel functionality - Slicer? [image]

Not very familiar with VBA!

Comment: You mean this kind of design alongside filter option, ... is your preferred output?

Comment: Yes.  And the result should be extracted into Excel.